# How do I augment Active Directory users in Open Directory?

Tags: osx-server, network-user, portable-home-directory

I've done this in the past, but I barely remember anymore.

I'd like to augment Active Directory (AD) users so they're able to use network home folders when the log in to Macs; they don't won't use Roaming Profiles, the AD equivalent, so this kinda has to be done in macOS Server.

I've found a lot of info about adding the users to Open Directory (OD) groups and on OD groups give access to services on macOS, that is correct for the standard web services (and Profile Manager) it offers but to set a network home folder the options are displayed only in individual users cards in the Server app.

Apple's documentation details this but only for other OD server users, not for AD users, it merely mentions the process is called "augmenting".

Using the Server app I tried exporting the AD users (completes successfully) and then importing the users to OD but that part completes, shows no errors whatsoever but also doesn't import anything. Then I tried importing the very same list that wouldn't import in OD in the local directory (local accounts) which completed just as the failed import but this didn't fail. I got all users from AD in the local directory which is useless for this purpose. That said, the home folder drop down becomes available for local users so I tried making it work but failed.

[image: Views of User and Group cards in Server.app]

> With a proxy, I intercepted the address for [Server app's help contents](https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.4/). Like macOS it has been dumbed down and has become less useful each iteration, so I'm lowering the number in the address bar to go back to other versions hopefully there's something. I'm only getting started though and it was *really* slimmed down for real. It'll take a while to fine anything on my own at this pace.

Using Profile Manager's mobility payloads I tried setting the network home folder buy it broke down the address, starting from the scheme (`smb://`), into a UNIX-style path starting with `//` that threw me off to the wrong path because that is actually valid in some cases, like `smbfs` which happens to be the protocol used to mount the home folders, but what it actually did was to create a weird path on `/`. It didn't begin with `//` at all, but as you probably know, Apple tends to hide things from the user to make it more "presentable", to put it some way.

I could try creating the users manually with throwaway passwords but I don't know how to keep them, or even put them in sync so that data still comes from AD, and lastly, there this user with a single character username where OD requires at least 2-character usernames, the only way I to create that in OD I think is using some automated method of creating the users, like importing it (which was successful on the local directory) otherwise it can't be created.

I appreciate your advice on this. I just converted a disk from APFS to HFS+ so it can be shared over AFP, just in case it's needed.

### Environment

All Macs are the same major, minor version of **High Sierra**. There are newer systems but all will be reverted back to High Sierra eventually.

Kerberos is working correctly, services are kerberized, Macs have no problems using *Windows Integrated Authentication* on this like SMB3 shares or SSO into other non-Windows servers/services, e.g; [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org).